# Click event is not firing when using custom jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

I am new to JQuery and am trying to use a plugin I found online to flip images.I am using the plugin available http://www.hieu.co.uk/blog/index.php/imageswitch/

I added the js library in my asp.net project and used the flipOut method mentioned in the library.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var ImgIdx = 2;
        var ImgName = "slash";
        $(document).ready(function () {

            $("img#image").click(function () {
                if (ImgIdx > 4)
                    ImgIdx = 2;
                ImgName = ImgName + ImgIdx + ".jpg";
                ImgIdx = ImgIdx + 1;
                if ($(this).hasClass("fadeout")) {
                    // $(this).fadeTo('slow', 1);
                    $(this).toggleClass("fadeout");
                    $(this > img).ImageSwitch({ Type: "FlipIn", NewImage: "slash2.jpg" });

                }
                else {
                    $(this).fadeTo('slow', 0.5);

                    // FlipIn
                    $(this).toggleClass("fadeout");
                    $(this).ImageSwitch({ Type: "FlipIn", NewImage: "slash3.jpg" });
}});});
</script>
<html><body>
 <asp:Image ID ="image" ImageUrl= "slash2.jpg" runat="server"></body></html>
```

The problem is : this works fine when i perform the first click, but  on successive clicks nothing happens. I tried to put alert messages inside the click event, but since the 2nd and successive clicks are not firing, even alert messages are not showing up.
I am using ASP.NET 3.5.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ASP, but wait does `runat="server"` means. In order to jQuery to work the DOM elment must be created in the document.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, had this same problem when I first started. When you call the line:

```
 $("img#image").click(function () {
 }
```

You are only binding the event to existing elements on the page. My guess is that your plugin uses AJAX, which dynamically loads items. If you are trying to access dynamically loaded content, use [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

```
$(document).on('click', 'img#image', function()
{
    //do stuff
});
```

Comment: `.on()` is new with jQuery 1.7 use `.live()` if you do not use the latest version of jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

use html img tag instead of using Asp.net one. it will only action on server not on client. Jquery is the javascript framwork which only work client machine. and if you are using the id specified dont use it with img like

```
$("#image").click(function () { //your code here });
```